# Create a PHP resquest from values of different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to obtain in one request two values from different tables, but I want to filer only one of this elements. I'm getting a syntax error:

`{"estado":"1","meta":{"errorInfo":["42000",1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN users' at line 8"]}}`

This is my code:

```
 public static function getById($idMeta)
{
    // Consulta de la meta
    $consulta = "SELECT idMeta,
                        titulo,
                         descripcion,
                         prioridad,
                         fechaLim,
                         id_evento
                         FROM meta2 INNER JOIN users ON nombre
                         WHERE meta2.idMeta = ?";

    try {
        // Preparar sentencia
        $comando = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consulta);
        // Ejecutar sentencia preparada
        $comando->execute(array($idMeta));
        // Capturar primera fila del resultado
        $row = $comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Aquí puedes clasificar el error dependiendo de la excepción
        // para presentarlo en la respuesta Json
        return $e;
    }
}
```

So when I tried to do the request without the filter(WHERE) it worked well but with "WHERE idMeta=?" it doesn`t work.

New error:

```
{"estado":"1","meta":{"errorInfo":["23000",1052,"Column 'idMeta' in field list is ambiguous"]}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're just using the wrong syntax. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: So with the new code(edited) I got this error: {"estado":"1","meta":{"errorInfo":["23000",1052,"Column 'idMeta' in field list is ambiguous"]}}

Comment: `Select meta2.idMeta ...`

Comment: Like this? "SELECT meta2.idMeta,
                            meta2.titulo,
                             meta2.descripcion,
                             meta2.prioridad,
                             meta2.fechaLim,
                            meta2.id_evento
                             FROM meta2 INNER JOIN users ON users.nombre
                             WHERE meta2.idMeta = ? ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you lose `join_condition` for `JOIN` it should be something as following

```
FROM meta2 INNER JOIN users ON users.id=meta2.user_id
```